# pythonanywhere bash No such file or directory?

Tags: python

Good morning.

Virtual environment cannot be executed in the current project.

The virtual environment folder looks normal.

However, it cannot be executed with the source command.

In my case, can I just reinstall the virtual environment?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UBax.png)

Comment: Please do not post [screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/711006). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, you have used `cd` to move into the directory `~/venv/bin`, and then you're trying to run the command `source venv/bin/activate`.  That is failing because the path of the script in the command you are running assumes that you are in the directory `~`.

If you have already used `cd` to navigate to the directory containing the file `activate`, you should just tell bash to source the file of that name in the current working directory, with the command `source ./activate`.